# How can I move information from my browser to my server-side code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-modules

I'm trying to make a simple weather app using Express and Node.js. In order to do this I need to get the latitude and longitude of the user automatically. I know how to do this via the browser using HTML5 Geolocation (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp). However, I can't do this from my server-side Express code. How can I create client-side code that gets the latitude and longitude from the browser, then sends it to my server-side code?

Comment: Have you googled how to send data from a client to a server?

Answer (score 1):

You would probably use an Ajax call to send the lat/long to the server from your browser Javascript code.  In modern browsers, you can use the [`fetch()` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to send an Ajax call.  The older interface for Ajax is [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Example:

```
fetch('/api/setLatLong', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(latLongData)
}).then(result => {
   // process returned data here
});
```

In the above example, you replace `/api/setLatLong` with whatever URL you want your server to receive the lat/long data on.  You then code a route on your server to receive that data.  You would presumably correlate that with a user by using a cookie or login session and then probably store the lat/long data in a user session on the server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where would my browser Javascript code live? Would it just be associated with an HTML file?

Comment: @GabeLevin - It would be in a `<script>` tag in an HTML file that is loaded into the browser.  And, typically the Ajax call would be run on some sort of user event in the web page (button click, key, mouse click, upon page load, etc...).

Comment: So I've gotten my script working. I get the coordinates, then place them inside two fields inside an invisible form. From there my script submits the form, thereby sending a POST request. I've confirmed that my server-side code is receiving the POST request, but how do I grab the data found in my two fields?

Comment: @GabeLevin - See https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters#toc-post-parameters for an example.